# How do i pass more things on getServerSideProps() in Next.js

Tags: javascript, web, next.js

I dont know if this a dumb question, but im working with a django api, and im trying to implement pagination on the search page, im very new to Next.js, ive search the web for an answer but nothing, here is the code, from the error, it made me believe that i cant pass "context" and "query : {page = 1}" at the same time, or something like that, is there any workaround this?

```js
import Video from '../../components/video'

const VideosSearch = ({results: videos, page}) => {
    return(
        <>
        <div>
            {videos.length > 0 && videos.map ((video) =>
            <Video key={video.id} {...video} />)}
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => router.push(`/videos?page=${page + 1}`)}> next </button>
        </>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context, {query: {page = 1}}){
    const start = +page === 1 ? 0 : (+page - 1) * 3
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/videos/?offset=${start}&ordering=-list_date&search=${context.params.query}`)


    const json = await res.json()
    const videos = json
    return{
        props: {
            results: videos.results,
            page: +page
        }
    }
}

export default VideosSearch
```

It gives me

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

oh and btw this is from /pages/search/[query].js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to access the params and query on the *context* object. [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) will only receive a single context parameter with the various keys.

Assuming you have `/pages/search/[query].jsx` which supports `/search/sith` or `/search/sith?page=2`

You need to modify slightly as per:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const page = context.query.hasOwnProperty('page') ? parseInt(context.query.page, 10) : 1;

    const start = (page - 1) * 3;

    console.info(context.params.query, page, start);

    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/videos/?offset=${start}&ordering=-list_date&search=${context.params.query}`)

    const json = await res.json()
    const videos = json;

    return{
        props: {
            results: videos.results,
            page: page
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great, but i have one more question, how do i access the "page" from the component?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean–where do you want to access the page variable?

Comment: I need the variable in the VideosSearch component

Comment: ```const VideosSearch = ({videos, page}) => {```

Answer (score 1):

Actually context parameter has everything you need

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {...}
```

to get parameter from url do this

```
const { page, query}= context.req.params
```